# Как изменить размер Label, Visual C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Собственно код:

```
Form Form2 = new Form1();
Form2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 300);
Form2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
Form2.MaximizeBox = false;
Form2.MinimizeBox = false;
Form2.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
Form2.Text = "CryptLocker Moscow";


Label text_for_user = new Label();
text_for_user.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
text_for_user.Top = 100;
text_for_user.AutoSize = false;
text_for_user.Text = "HEY, USER!!!";
text_for_user.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
text_for_user.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
text_for_user.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", text_for_user.Font.Size);
text_for_user.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
Form2.Controls.Add(text_for_user);

Application.Run(Form2);
```

Так вот, строчка:

```
text_for_user.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
```

является бессмысленной, так как есть она, нет ее, стоит ли там 50,50 или 500,500, при исполнении программы размер текста по факту не меняется. Что делать?

Comment: Свойство `Dock` часом ручное значение `Size` не перекрывает?

Comment: Сейчас проверим.

Comment: Оказалось вообще, что свойство   text_for_user.Size это условный размер, границы, нашего Label. А как тогда увеличить размер текста?

Comment: Зачем его увеличивать вручную, если есть `AutoSize`?

Answer (score 2):

```
Form Form2 = new Form1();
Form2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 300);
Form2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
Form2.MaximizeBox = false;
Form2.MinimizeBox = false;
Form2.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
Form2.Text = "CryptLocker Moscow";
//Написание текста

Label text_for_user = new Label();
text_for_user.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
text_for_user.Top = 150;
text_for_user.Left = 500;
text_for_user.AutoSize = false;
text_for_user.Text = "HEY, USER!!!";
text_for_user.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
text_for_user.Size= new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
text_for_user.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 24, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
//text_for_user.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
Form2.Controls.Add(text_for_user);

Application.Run(Form2);
```

Answer (score 1):

В свойствах нужно найти Autosize и выбрать False)